# Find all div id's except one and remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove classes from div's that have a ID that start and end with same pattern.

```
$('[id^="mystr"][id$="_mynd"] #ednv').removeClass('vision');
```

this works for all divs on my site, but i would like to exclude one specific div at path #mystr645_mynd > #ednv i dont want this specific div's to be affected?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here because anyway it can only have one element `#ednv` on document context. Do you mean you want to exclude the div parent of `#ednv`?!

Comment: None of the answers will work with this as-is as your final selector is an ID. IDs must be unique. It might as well be just `$('#ednv')` at the moment. You need to clarify the problem with an example of the HTML.

Comment: IDs are unique per html file..

Answer (score 5):

Use [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo-class selector. Although you should use `class` instead of `id` for a group of elements since `id` should be unique and only get selected the first.

```
$('[id^="mystr"][id$="_mynd"]:not(#mystr645_mynd) .ednv').removeClass('vision'); 
//----------------------------^^^^---------------^^^---------
```